# How to change Port of Apache ACE?

Tags: osgi, port, apache-ace

I want to change the port of Apache ACE to 80. How can I do that? I could not find any documentation for that. I have tried by changing value of key `Dorg.osgi.service.http.port` in file `platform.properties` from 8080 to 80. But after this, i am not able to login in Apache ace. It gives invalid username & password message. However, i am able to login through same credentials if i run it on port 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current release (1.0.0) you can achieve what you were initially trying by removing following lines from laucher.properties that resides inside server(-allinone).jar

```
org.apache.ace.server.port=8080
org.osgi.service.http.port=8080
```

Answer (score 2):

The properties in following files needs to be updated for port change.

1. platform.properties

   ```
    -Dorg.osgi.service.http.port
   ```
2. conf/org.apache.ace.webui.vaadin.cfg

   ```
      aceHost
      obrUrl
   ```
3. conf/org.apache.ace.server.activation.impl.cfg

   ```
      hostName
      obrUrl
   ```
4. conf/org.apache.ace.discovery.property.cfg

   ```
      serverURL
   ```
5. conf/org.apache.ace.deployment.provider.repositorybased.cfg

   ```
      url
   ```
6. conf/org.apache.ace.configurator.useradmin.task.UpdateUserAdminTask.cfg

   ```
      repositoryLocation
   ```
7. conf/org.apache.ace.client.automation.cfg

   ```
      hostName
   ```
8. conf/org.apache.ace.activation.matcher.cfg

   ```
      repositoryURL
   ```

Comment: @vinod: Could you explain which files need which changes? This might help future readers solve the problem faster.

Comment: @BjörnPollex- Updated the answer with the details of properties

Comment: The current "trunk" version has simplified this a lot. We have a single property now that you can set. This property is used as a variable in the configurations mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

With 1.0.0 I was not able to pass in parameters via -D (which were commented out previously).
What worked for me was setting port numbers in server-allinone.jar/launcher.properties.

Answer (score 0):

With Ace 1.0, we used command line properties to change the port (to 8083 in our case):

```
java -Dorg.apache.ace.server.port=8083 -Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8083 -jar server-allinone.jar
```

This did not work any more with Ace 2.0.1, ie we could change the port but authentication would not work. I identified the properties to be changed in launcher.properties but set them on the command line instead of changing launcher.properties. This keeps from having to recreate the jar. The command line I use is:

```
java -Dorg.apache.ace.server=localhost:8083 -Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8083 -Dorg.apache.ace.obr=localhost:8083 -jar server-allinone.jar
```